# How to set textbox and commandbutton?

Tags: vba, excel

```
UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = CStr(Range("activecell").Value)
UserForm1.Show
```

I want to show value for active cell of range.
Which I combine with command(next)button.
So whenever I click(command(next)button, I want the text box shows the value of active cell.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Ridwan

Comment: Do you mean `ActiveCell` ? or a Named Range "currentcell"?

Comment: My apologize, I mean activecell.

Comment: Try `UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = ActiveCell.Value`

Comment: Hi Shai, It showing the cell that I want, but I need the next step. The next step is, when I click command button, I want it shows the next cell.

Comment: next cell is the next cell down ? in the next row ? if yes use `UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = ActiveCell.Offset(1).Value`

Comment: Yes you are right. But is still doesnt work. I have this code for the commandbutton.

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try...

Place the following line of code on a Standard Module like Module1.

**Module1 Code:**

```
Public Rng As Range
```

**Code on UserForm Module:**

```
'Assuming the name of CommndButton is cmdNext and name of TextBox is TextBox1
Private Sub cmdNext_Click()
If Rng Is Nothing Then
    Set Rng = ActiveCell
Else
    Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1)
End If
Me.TextBox1.Value = Rng.Value
End Sub
```

Change the name of CommandButton and TextBox in the code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As slready told you by Shai Radi, your code should be:

```
With UserForm1
    .TextBox1.Text = ActiveCell.Value
    .Show
End With
```

While as to your “next step”, your commandbutton click event could be

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Me.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```